# How to dynamically bold specific data in html table

Tags: python, html, css, flask

Here, in my page, there is a table will responded by the server and the table looks like this

[image]

the table is a [Pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/) created by `df.to_html()` method, and I added `<b></b>` to the max value in every column.

But my css can't print the max with bold font, so ,here is the css of the table

```
<style>
    body            { font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;}
    a, h1, h2       { color: #377ba8; }
    h1, h2          { margin: 0; }
    h1              { border-bottom: 2px solid #eee; }
    h2              { font-size: 1.2em; }
    table.dataframe, .dataframe th, .dataframe td {
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align:center;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }
    .male th {
        background-color: #add8e6;
        color: white;
    }
    .female th {
        background-color: #77dd77;
        color: white;
    }
    tr:nth-child(odd)       { background-color:#eee; }
    tr:nth-child(even)  { background-color:#fff; }
    tr:hover            { background-color: #ffff99;}
</style>
```

In python, the table looks like this(pandas dataframe)

```
In [310]: df
Out[310]:
   1  2
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
```

And the max value of each column is not all the same based on the input from the page. So how can I dynamically bold the max value in each column( lenght, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)?.

My web server is Flask(Python)

Comment: i dont know about the python. but i can say about html and css. here your bold tag not coming as html tag it is coming as a text inside table. so it will not work as you expect. check something about it first in your python and table.

Comment: The problem is that the tags that you added (<b>) got escaped and aren't working as HTML tags.

Comment: @pathaktejpal, yes, thank you, you are right, But how can I dynamically bold the max value in css level not in the sever.

Comment: personally i feel it should be handled by server level not css level. but if you want it that way then there are many option for you where you use needed selecter.

check this link: 
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048